# How to join two tables based on conditon in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I need to Join two table with respective to two columns

1. Stu_id (Table 1) -  Stu_id   (Table 2)
2. Perf_yr(Table 1) -  yr_month (Table 2)

`perf_yr` starts on every year  Sept to Aug.
`Perf_yr` should match the `yr_month` based on `Perf_yr` start and end Month

Table 1

```
Stu_id    Roll_No    Avg_marks  Perf_yr 
 1       100244         72      2017
 2       200255         62      2018
 3       100246         68      2019
```

Table 2

```
Stu_id   Subject    Marks   yr_month
 1      Maths      70      201609
 1      Science    69      201701   
 1      Social     74      201712 
 2      Maths      60      201709
 2      Science    61      201801   
 2      Social     62      201808
 3      Maths      65      201810
 3      Science    64      201912   
 3      Social     72      201902
```

Output

```
Stu_id    Roll_No    Avg_marks  Perf_yr Subject  Marks  yr_month
 1       100244         72      2017     Maths   70    201609
 1       100244         72      2017     Science 70    201701
 2       200255         62      2018     Maths   60    201709
 2       200255         62      2018     Science 61    201801 
 2       200255         62      2018     Social  62    201808
 3       100246         68      2019     Maths   65    201810
 3       100246         68      2019     Science 64    201912
 3       100246         68      2019     Social  72    201902
```

I TRIED :

```
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM 

(SELECT * FROM TABLE1 )A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM TABLE)B
ON 
A.Stu_id = B.Stu_id
AND
A.Perf_yr = B.Yr_Month
```

BUT IT WONT GIVE THE DESIRED RESULT BECAUSE THE CONDITION IS NOT SATISFYING THE PERF YR START AND END DATE .

Comment: Please update the question to include the SQL code you tried and explain why you think it didn't work to get your expected output.

Comment: Also, why is this question tagged both `[sql-server]` and `[oracle]`? Do you really need an answer for two different RDBMS platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse eg 201609 as a date, add 4 months to it, then match it to the year from the other table. Adding 4 months converts a date range 201609-201708 into being 201701-201712 - we only care about the year part:

```
SELECT * FROM
   t1
   INNER JOIN t2
   ON
     t1.stu_id = t2.stu_id AND
     t1.Perf_yr  = EXTRACT(year FROM ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(t2.yr_month, 'YYYYMM'), 4))
```

This is oracle. The same logic will work for SQLS, you'll just need to adjust the functions used-

```
CONVERT(date, t2.yr_month+'01', 112) -- Convert yyyymmdd to a date
DATEADD(month, x, 4) -- add 4 months to x
YEAR(x) -- extract year from date x
```